# Posting form inside switch-case statement inside th:each

Tags: html, hibernate, thymeleaf

Can I post element with form nested in switch-case statement, which is nested in for-each loop?

```
                    <tr th:each="item : ${individualTransactions}">
                        <td><span th:text="${item.itemName}"> </span></td>
                        <td><span th:text="${item.itemDescription}"> </span></td>
                        <td><span th:text="${item.itemCost}"> </span></td>
                        <td>
                            <div th:switch="${item.isUsed}">
                                <span th:case="true"> USED </span>
                                <span th:case="false">
                                    <form action="post"
                                        th:action="@{/student/transactions}"
                                        th:object="${item}"
                                        method="post">
                                        <input type="submit" value="USE ITEM"/>
                                    </form>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  In Thymeleaf, the `th:object` of a `<form />` has to be a model variable (and can't be a temporary variable like `${item}` -- which is created in your `th:each`).

That being said, you can have multiple forms created with objects, but you have to do manual work and can't use the regular thymeleaf `th:object` and `th:field` attributes.

Comment: Posting only the id of wanted item solved the case.